# python newbie - where is my if/else wrong?

Tags: python, if-statement

Complete beginner so I'm sorry if this is obvious!

I have a file which is name | +/- or IG_name | 0 in a long list like so -

```
S1      +
IG_1    0
S2      -
IG_S3   0
S3      +
S4      -
dnaA    +
IG_dnaA 0
```

Everything which starts with IG_ has a corresponding name. I want to add the + or - to the IG_name. e.g. IG_S3 is + like S3 is.

The information is gene names and strand information, IG = intergenic region. Basically I want to know which strand the intergenic region is on.

What I think I want:

```
open file
for every line, if the line starts with IG_*
    find the line with *
    print("IG_" and the line it found)
else 
    print line
```

What I have:

```
with open(sys.argv[2]) as geneInfo:
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as origin:
            for line in origin:
                    if line.startswith("IG_"):
                            name = line.split("_")[1]
                            nname = name[:-3]
                            for newline in geneInfo:
                                    if re.match(nname, newline):
                                            print("IG_"+newline)
                    else:
                            print(line)
```

where origin is the mixed list and geneInfo has only the names not IG_names.

With this code I end up with a list containing only the else statements.

```
S1  +

S2  -

S3  +

S4  -

dnaA    +
```

My problem is that I don't know what is wrong to search so I can (attempt) to fix it!

Comment: This would be a good opportunity to get familiar with stepping through your code with a debugger. Most IDEs will have one. You can  also throw in print statements to compare what you think should happen to what actually is.

Comment: That said, your write-up only mentions a single file, and your code deals with two, so I'd kind of expect a bug there.

Comment: Apologies!   I didn't make it obvious enough! 

The second file is like so:

` S1 +
 S2 -
 S3 +
 S4 -
 dnaA +` 

Can you recommend a IDE? I've been doing this on a server/command line.

Comment: Pycharm is glorious. There are also command line debuggers (don't know any offhand) if you need to be in that environment for some reason.

Comment: What do you want for `IG_1`? In other words, if * is not found, what should be stored against it?

Comment: There is definitely a corresponding * for every IG_*. The IG's are generated using the names list.  Unfortunately my example wasn't helpful, sorry!

Comment: @Holly meh, I went forwards anyway to give an approach that will handle it regardless. Besides, it's probably best to code defensively i.e. account for the unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is some step-by-step annotated code that hopefully does what you want (though instead of using `print` I have aggregated the results into a list so you can actually make use of it). I'm not quite sure what happened with your existing code (especially how you're processing two files?)

```
s_dict = {}
ig_list = []

with open('genes.txt', 'r') as infile: # Simulating reading the file you pass in sys.argv
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith('IG_'):
            ig_list.append(line.split()[0]) # Collect all our IG values for later
        else:
            s_name, value = line.split()    # Separate out the S value and its operator
            s_dict[s_name] = value.strip()  # Add to dictionary to map S to operator

# Now you can go back through your list of IG values and append the appropriate operator
pulled_together = [] 

for item in ig_list:
    s_value = item.split('_')[1]
    # The following will look for the operator mapped to the S value. If it is 
    # not found, it will instead give you 'not found'
    corresponding_operator = s_dict.get(s_value, 'Not found') 
    pulled_together.append([item, corresponding_operator])

print ('List structure')
print (pulled_together)
print ('\n')

print('Printout of each item in list')
for item in pulled_together:
    print(item[0] + '\t' + item[1])
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments along with your code! Extremely helpful! 

I think I need to find a tutorial on dictionary making!

The main problem here is that I'm a biologist, learning as I go to "do the bioinformatics" :)

Comment: @Holly you're welcome. I'm a Chemical Engineer turning data scientist, so I understand :) The reason for a dictionary here is that it makes use of hash tables so that you can very quickly find the value you want without reading all values in the data structure. You can think of a list as the Oxford dictionary in non-alphabetical order, forcing you to (potentially) traverse the entire thing to find one word, and a dictionary as, well, a normal version of our Oxford dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
 nname = name[:-3]
```

Python's slicing through list is very powerful, but can be tricky to understand correctly.

When you write [:-3], you take everything except the last three items. The thing is, if you have less than three element in your list, it does not return you an error, but an empty list.

I think this is where things does not work, as there are not much elements per line, it returns you an empty list. If you could tell what do you exactly want it to return there, with an example or something, it would help a lot, as i don't really know what you're trying to get with your slicing.

Comment: ha, what I was trying to do was slice away the last three "characters". In my head this removed the "\t + \n" that would be present. Another thing to add to my list of needed tutorials !

Comment: the ideal situation:

` S1      +
 IG_S1   +
 S2      -
 IG_S3   +
 S3      +
 S4      -
 dnaA    +
 IG_dnaA +`

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

# Read and store all the gene info lines, keyed by name
gene_info = dict()                            
with open(sys.argv[2]) as gene_info_file:
    for line in gene_info_file:
        tokens = line.split()
        name = tokens[0].strip()
        gene_info[name] = line


# Read the other file and lookup the names
with open(sys.argv[1]) as origin_file:
    for line in origin_file:
        if line.startswith("IG_"):
                name = line.split("_")[1]
                nname = name[:-3].strip()
                if nname in gene_info:
                    lookup_line = gene_info[nname]
                    print("IG_" + lookup_line)
                else:
                    pass # what do you want to do in this case?
        else:
            print(line)
```

Comment: This looks like what I was trying to achieve!   Looks like I skipped a couple of steps, and needed to split my loops.  Thanks for your help.